# Why is docker listing files in empty directory?

Tags: docker

Docker is listing files in directory but they are not visible in explorer or command line. I have created these files using docker. What sorcery is this?

I am using windows 10 enterprise edition and docker community version 19.03.1.

```sh
PS C:\Users\mrigank.varma\.aws> docker run --rm -v ~\.aws:/data alpine ls /data

config
credentials

PS C:\Users\mrigank.varma\.aws> ls

PS C:\Users\mrigank.varma\.aws>
```

Comment: Please confirm that the 'alpine' image you're using is straight from DockerHub and not your own build. If it is bespoke, please include your Dockerfile in the question.

Comment: Alpine image is straight from docker hub.

Comment: What is the output of `ls ~\.aws` (executed in the same shell where the docker command shows some files)?

Comment: I just tried the same on a Windows 10 machine and WFM. There must be something you're not telling us. What is your Docker version?

Comment: Can you please post what `New-Item -Path '~\.aws\credentials' -ItemType File` command outputs?

Comment: You could also try with another image, w.g. `ubuntu`

Comment: One more idea: see if using an absolute path works.

Comment: I am using docer community edition version 19.03.1.
tried New-Item -Path '~\.aws\credentials' -ItemType File doesnt list anything.
tried absolute path as well. no success.

Comment: I am using "docker run --rm -it -v ~/.aws:/root/.aws dtjohnson/aws-azure-login --configure" this command to generate file inside .aws folder. Github: https://github.com/sportradar/aws-azure-login

Answer (score 5):

Your files are probably 'hidden' in Windows, but since they are not 'dot' files in Linux, they are shown when you list the directory via the container.

Check your folder again in Windows Explorer with hidden files showing. Bear in mind they may be system files, so make sure you do this 'as Administrator.' Other methods are available - see https://pureinfotech.com/show-hidden-files-folders-windows-10/

Another option in Windows may be `Get-ChildItem -hidden` in Powershell (see comments 1 & 2 from Dorian below.)

Comment: If `ls -a` doesn't work, the Powershell command is `Get-ChildItem --hidden`

Comment: My previous command is wrong. The command need only one hyphen for the `hidden` parameter, like this: `Get-ChildItem -hidden`.

Comment: ls -a doesnt work on windows. Unfortunately "Get-ChildItem -hidden" doesnt show any files as well.

Comment: FYI: these files are created by docker.

Comment: I'm sure the problem is related to hidden files. I can't think why the alpine image would be generating those files. Could you follow the instruction in here?

https://pureinfotech.com/show-hidden-files-folders-windows-10/

(presuming you're using Windows 10!)

Comment: I am using windows 10. Tried "dir -Force", same result. I think the issue is something else, because if there is some hidden files, I can't create the file with same name; no matter what.

Comment: I understand, logically it doesnt make any sence, but its happening. This issue is replicating, just try to create a file using docker in any hidden folder. If I find success finding the root cause, will create bug for docker. This started last few months.